# Spring Parameterized/Theories JUnit Tests

Tags: java, junit

I'm looking to combine the flexibility of [Spring Profiles and Configurations](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles/) with the parallel running of JUnit tests which utilize either the [Parameterized](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html) or [Theories](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/junit/junit/4.8.2/junit-4.8.2-javadoc.jar!/org/junit/experimental/theories/Theories.html) annotation.  Is there any way to incorporate all of these features to get my unit tests running?

The problem I keep running into is the parameters need access to an injected bean, which isn't possible since the function annotated with @Parameters or @DataPoints is supposed to be static.  I'd really hate to have to wire that into each class or even a static function somewhere because I'd like to quickly be able to switch profiles without having to change Java code.  Is this possible?

Comment: There is an article to your question:

https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2016/02/13/writing-parameterized-tests-with-spring-and-junit-4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the [ticket](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5292) for this request.  It seems the attached file has some issues though.  Looks like it's been a feature request for quite some time now.

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for a solution of this problem too. And there is one ! But as it comes from somebody's blog, I can't take the credit for it however. :-)

Unfortunately I can't find the original blog any more...

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/beans.xml")
public class MyTest {

  private final File file;

  public MyTest(final File file) {
    this.file = file;
  }

  @Autowired
  private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

  private TestContextManager testContextManager;

  @Parameterized.Parameters
  public static Collection<File[]> getFilesToTest() throws Exception {
    return getValidFiles();
  }

  @Before
  public void setUpSpringContext() throws Exception {
    testContextManager = new TestContextManager(getClass());
    testContextManager.prepareTestInstance(this); // does the autowiring !
  }

  @Test
  public void testInTransactionContext() throws Exception {
    new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager).execute(new TransactionCallback() {
      public Object doInTransaction(final TransactionStatus status) {
        status.setRollbackOnly();
        try {
          ... run the test ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return null;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hard to see what this gains us without seeing the implementation of getValidFiles is.  We've though about a method similar to this which would call a webservice to return our parameters.

Comment: It's just an example. :-) As long as it's a collection of arrays of objects (who came up with that by the way ?). Methods annotated with @Parameterized.Parameters will be called once to get the collection. After, for each element in the collection, an instance will be created using the constructor (hence the constructor with a File argument).

Comment: My hope is to be able to inject the parameters though.

Comment: You mean as general properties for application context ?

Comment: For example, what if you want your parameters (test data) to be someService.getSomeData(), and someService is autowired in?